How many bits are needed to distinguish functions over bit vectors given a maximum number of twos-complement addition operations?
Say we have two distinct functions $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ and $g(x_1, ..., x_n)$, where each $x_i$ is a bit vector of length $B$. Each function consists of an arbitrary number of bitwise operations like AND, OR, and XOR, plus at most $M$ distinct1 twos-complement addition operations. What is the minimum value of $B$ needed to distinguish $f$ and $g$?
There are a few cases that I've been able to think through on my own:

I know that $B > M$, since with $B = M = 1$ we can't distinguish $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 + x_2$ from $g(x_1, x_2) = x_1 \oplus x_2$. Intuitively, this is because the carry out from the first bit position is never used.
For $M = 0$, $B = 1$ is obviously sufficient. Without any addition operations, there is no way for data to propagate between bit positions.
For $M = 1$, $B = 2$ is not sufficient to distinguish $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 + x_2$ from $g(x_1, x_2) = x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus [(x_1 \land x_2) + (x_1 \land x_2)]$. Intuitively, this is because the carry out from the first bit position is only used to compute the second bit position, and does not propagate any further.
For $M = 1$, $B = 3$, I have not been able to come up with a counterexample. It seems to be sufficient, since it uses the carry-out from the first bit position to compute both the second bit position, and the carry in to the third bit position.

Following from these cases, it feels like $B = M + 2$ is sufficient to distinguish $f$ and $g$, however I have not been able to prove this to my satisfaction.
1 I'm not sure what the correct mathematical term is here. By "distinct addition operations", I mean to say "addition operations that produce different outputs". This means that $f(x_1, x_2) = (x_1 + x_2) + (x_1 + x_2)$ has only two distinct addition operations, and more generally a function with $M$ distinct addition operations can compute the left shift operation $x \ll M$.
